# To compare to column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns in two different tables.
First column is number like `0493484402` and second column is audit_detail like `'addr_mastersubscription has changed from 32488141893 to 32488141973'`.

I have to check whether first column value is present or not in second column's entire string.

If the number is not present I need that number as output

Comment: What is your expected output? `32493484402` is not in posted string, so do you want a "not present" flag? Or an empty set? Furthermore, if the first column has a value of `4881418` would that count as a match or not?

Comment: If the number is not present in second column I want that number and number should be 11 or 10 digit

Answer (score 4):

You could use `LIKE` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.audit_detail LIKE '%' || t1.col1 || '%';
```

We can also use `INSTR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON INSTR(t2.audit_detail, t1.col1) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, with solution of `like` and `instr`, you must have some delimeter which comes before and after your string in second column. Else `1` as a fisrt column will match eith `123` in second column.

Looking at the sample data, you can use space as a delimeter. But you will need leading and trailing space compulsory in your second column for matching first column.

You can use something like this:

```
Select * 
Table1 t1 join table2 t2
On ' ' || t2.second_column || ' ' like '% ' || t1.first_column || ' %';
```